# What is the usage of a class whose destructor is deleted?

Tags: c++

We can define a class with its destructor deleted:

```
class A {
public : 
    A() = default;
    ~A() = delete;
};
```

Then, we cannot define a variable of type A.
However, we can use new operator to allocate and construct an object of type A in the heap and we can never delete it.
I want to know whether this class has any usage in the real-world?

Comment: You _might_ want to `delete` the destructor of a singleton.

Comment: There are some cases or "intentional memory leaks" for singletons, where doing any cleanup is more trouble than it's worth; application-wide parameters or logging come to mind. A deleted destructor may be a part of such pattern.

Comment: The second duplicate has a slightly different focus, but many of its answers do touch on the reasons for deleting the destructor.

Comment: That second dupe is the right one imho.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'm not sure, AFAICT all the answers just say "don't do it", not any reason why you would (be tempted to) do it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight,Thanks for your help!